# TableView data for a Specific CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I'm not being able to load the data that is related to the collection cell row.
For test purposes, I printed the flow of the program and it seems that it does all the CollectionView Cells before it goes to the tableView, even if I call the tableView.reload inside the cellForItemAt at CollectionView.
Any help will be appreciated.

PRINT STATEMENTS:
index path row CollectionView 0
index path row CollectionView 1
table view index path row TableView 0
table view index path row TableView 0

I have this collection in Firebase:
calendar
index: 0 (which is the CollectionCell indexPath.row)
title: "example 1 index 0"
index: 0
title: "example 2 index 0 "
index: 1
title: "test 1 index 1"

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

    cell?.tableView.delegate = self
    cell?.tableView.dataSource = self

    print("index path row CollectionView \(indexPath.row)")

        cell?.tableView.reloadData()

    return cell!
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if calEvent.count == 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return calEvent.count
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
        print("table view index path row TableView  \(indexPath.row)")
        if indexPath.row == calEvent.count {
            cell?.label.text = "no event"
        } else {
            cell?.label.text = calEvent[indexPath.row].title
        }
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

func populateDataSource(index: Int) {


    self.db.collection("calendar")

        .whereField("index", isEqualTo: index)

        .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error ) in
            if let e = error {
                print("error \(e)")
            } else {
                self.calEvent.removeAll()
                guard let snap = snapshot else { return  }
                for doc in (snap.documents) {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    print(doc.data())
                    let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                    guard let stamp = data["date"] as? Timestamp else {
                        return
                    }
                    let dateStamp = stamp.dateValue()
                    let newEvent = CalEvent(category: "", title: title, date: dateStamp, paciente: "")
                    self.calEvent.append(newEvent)

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `populateDataSource`?

Comment: I tried on viewDidLoad and on CollectionView cellforItem as below:       
    cell?.tableView.delegate = self
    cell?.tableView.dataSource = self
    
    print("index path row CollectionView \(indexPath.row)")
 //   populateDataSource(index: indexPath.row)
   // DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell?.tableView.reloadData()
        //  let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.calEvent.count - 1 , section:0)
        //  cell?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
   // }
    return cell!
}

Answer (score 0):

Firebase returns in a background thread. You are not reloading the `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` after the fetch has been completed and your `dataSource` has been populated. You need to add a reload method on the main thread. Something like this:

```
for doc in (snap.documents) { ... }

DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //reload here
}
```

Comment: I’m calling at CollectionView cellforItem, do I need to reload the collectionView? 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell =collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
    cell?.tableView.delegate = self
    cell?.tableView.dataSource  = self
 populateDataSource(index: indexPath.row)
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell?.tableView.reloadData()
   let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.calEvent.count - 1)} return cell!}

Comment: You should just call the population method in `viewDidLoad` and reload on the fetch completion like i posted above. Calling it in `cellForItem` will just cause the method to refetch data at every scroll which is unnecessarily expensive.